# How do I get all parts of my HUD to stick around in DX:HR

Tags: pc, deus-ex-human-revolution

So, I'm pretty sure when I started playing DX:HR, the display for my "hotbar," or 1-0 keys, was constantly around as long as I wasn't at Sarif Industries. Yet now, later in the game, I'm noticing that it fades out after a few seconds wherever I am, and only re-displays when I change items.

I have a terrible memory. I can't remember which item is tied to which number key. How do I get this thing to stick around and stop disappearing? Couldn't find anything that seemed to fit in the options menu, so I'm assuming it's a keyboard shortcut I accidentally hit...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I accidentally discovered that you can make the "hotbar" (yeah, I don't know the official name either) toggle between fixed and fade-out mode by pressing the <kbd>`</kbd> key (the one next to <kbd>1</kbd> used to toggle the console in most games).