# The HUD is gone / mispositioned?

Tags: pc, deus-ex-human-revolution

So I think I've broken the game a little. The entire HUD seems to have vanished, and there's no option setting, or button combination to get it back.
When changing zones, a little of the HUD comes back, but is in the completely wrong position:

[image]

So my questions are:

- What causes this?
- How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried changing the resolution in game, and changing it back?

Comment: @Bora Yes, and it doesn't change a thing :(

Comment: perhaps a relevant question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29268/how-do-i-get-all-parts-of-my-hud-to-stick-around-in-dxhr

Comment: @Bora That's only the hotbar, not the entire HUD.

Comment: I know, it's only a reference. I am not saying this question is redundant. edited my comment accordingly..

Comment: No idea why this happens. Happened to me too, but simply restarting the game fixed it for me.

Comment: @lunboks Tried that a few times as well, and it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of latest patch, this should now be fixed:

> Fixed an issue where the HUD would get permanently disabled for some players.

[Source](http://store.steampowered.com/news/6272/)

*(See edits for the cause of this bug)*

Comment: ....or wait for them to fix the bug, which may well correct the problem for existing savegames?

Comment: @jprete It's not really a solution, as we don't know when they are going to release a fix, and if it will even correct the problem for existing save games.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this issue before, it looks like my HUD was placed as if my screen was using a lower resolution.  Quicksaving and reloading did the trick for me.  As for what caused it, I'm not sure but it may have to do with me alt-tabbing quite a bit (I have a dual screen monitor and I hate not being able to play this game in windowed mode so I can use my 2nd screen).

Comment: I had similar issues once or twice and am also a prolific Alt-Tabber (but single screen) so that may well be the cause. Save/Load or Save/Quit Game/Load always worked for me.

Comment: Neither restarting, load, save/load helped. I'll dig a bit further in to the problem.

Answer (score -3):

The HUD is off because you are evil in the game the only way to turn the HUD on is to start over and be good and the HUD will stay on as long as you are good

Comment: Any source to back up that claim?